# Link Automation?

Tags: python, selenium

Some one please help me

I want to automate one link with python selenium, But am not able to do.
Below is my code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&amp;list_id=28446&amp;query_format=specific&amp;ctype=csv&amp;human=1']")).click()
```

Below is the inspect elements from browser

```
<a href="buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&amp;list_id=28446&amp;query_format=specific&amp;ctype=csv&amp;human=1"><img title="CSV Format" alt="CSV" src="images/csv.png" height="24" width="24"></a>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxCkg.png)

Note: Remaining connection part and everything is working fine, only am not able to connect this link

Comment: human=1 is a clue... is there a captcha?  Post the code you've tried so far and any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Code is working now